# Beck's original formulation of the precise tripleability theorem. Reference when considering reflexive pairs?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monads

[Thanks to MO's user Varkor](https://mathoverflow.net/a/404123/101848), we have access to [Beck's original untitled manuscript](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/Untitled+manuscript.pdf) where Beck first stated his precise tripleability theorem. Up to terminological isomorphism, the PTT as stated in p. 3 of Beck's manuscript coincides with Riehl's statement in *[Category Theory in Context](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf)*, Theorem 5.5.1. Consider now the following statement, identical to that of Riehl's except we add one italic word:

> (PTT*). A right adjoint functor $U:\mathsf{D}\to\mathsf{C}$ is monadic if and only if it creates coequalizers of *reflexive* $U$-split pairs.

(A pair of morphisms $f,g:x\rightrightarrows y$ in $\mathsf{D}$ is said to be *reflexive* if $f,g$ have a common section $s:y\to x$.)

The proof of PTT* is the same as Riehl's proof of PTT (Theorem 5.5.1 in her numbering): on the one hand, if $U$ is monadic, we already know that it creates coequalizers of *all* $U$-split pairs, so in particular it creates them for the pairs that are reflexive. We now look at Riehl's proof of the converse: there's only two instances where the hypothesis of $U$ creating coequalizers of reflexive $U$-split pairs is exploited, namely, she applies it to the following pairs, after noting that they are $U$-split:

1. $FUFA\underset{\epsilon_{FA}}{\stackrel{F\alpha}{\rightrightarrows}} FA$, in (5.5.2),
2. $FUFUD\underset{\epsilon_{FUD}}{\stackrel{FU\epsilon_D}{\rightrightarrows}} FUD$, in the last paragraph of the proof.

But these pairs are reflexive, common sections are given by $F\eta_A$ and $F\eta_{UD}$, respectively. Thus, it sufficed on the first place to just assume the hypothesis in PTT*.

My only question is:

> Do you know a reference of PTT*?

I've already looked in the following sources but I haven't found anything: Schubert, *Categories*; Barr, Wells, *[Toposes, Triples and Theories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/12/tr12.pdf)*; Riehl's book itself and Mac Lane, *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, VI.7 (and exercises in the section).

---

Interestingly, [the alternative formulation of PTT](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monadicity+theorem#BeckMonadicityTheoremAlternative) (stated already in the last page of Beck's manuscript) gives rise to the corresponding alternative formulation of PTT* (again by solely adding the word "reflexive"):

> Theorem 3.14. [Barr, Wells, *[Toposes, Triples and Theories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/12/tr12.pdf)*] A functor $U: \mathsf{D} \to \mathsf{C}$ is monadic if and only if
>
> 1. $U$ has a left adjoint.
> 2. $U$ reflects isomorphisms.
> 3. $\mathsf{D}$ has coequalizers of reflexive $U$-split coequalizer pairs and $U$ preserves them.